# Spring boot security : creating a microservice for authentification not contained in the UI part

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm creating a new  project which requires a microservice dedicated to user authentification.

All the examples that i found use the same project microservice both for UI and authentification(Creation of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter , Creation of UserDetailsService implementation)

So, how can i do to verify the user credentials on another microservice using spring boot security.

1- **UI project**

2- **Micorservice project** for *authentication* that check the *user credentials* and send to the UI project the answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Option1:* You still need pass the credentials from UI to Microservice but using a secured channel (e.g: https), then you can use some sort of session control (e.g: Authorisation Headers, Session Cookies). *Option2:* Use oAuth.